# Proxy apt get to https fails

Tags: ubuntu, apt, tinyproxy

I have a Proxy server setup for multiple Ubunut hosts to access apt repositories using tiny proxy.

I am trying to add a RabbitMQ host to get it's update from the same proxy but get the following error when running `apt update`:

`Err:6 https://packagecloud.io/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  Invalid response from proxy: HTTP/1.0 403 Filtered  Server: tinyproxy/1.8.4  Content-Type: text/html  Connection: close     [IP: 1.2.3.4 8888]`

The tiny proxy has a white list of domains it can access including `packagecloud.io`.

Why is it not working?

Comment: Did you check this? https://github.com/tinyproxy/tinyproxy/issues/162

Comment: I saw that, i don't believe that is the issue since i have other operations going through https successfully, my best hunch is that it's somethign related to the gpg key but since it not a reverse proxy i don't see any reason for it not to work.

Comment: Check your tinyproxy configuration. "Filtered" is an obvious clue that something is going on there.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that `https://packagecloud.io/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/ubuntu` is being redirected to `https://d28dx6y1hfq314.cloudfront.net` and so proxy blocks it